# Do C# static members get shared among calls to a Web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, static

I'm creating a Web site using C#/Asp.net. I want to minimize object creation by setting some classes and properties as static. But I don't want those objects to be reused by subsequent calls to the Web server. I want the static objects to be disposed of as soon as a request has been processed. And if, during processing, a new request comes in, I don't want the new request to see data in the prior request's static classes and properties. So, should I be using static or not?

Comment: Are you familiar with IOC or DI containers?

Comment: you should not ... if you wana minimize object creation(or rather later GC calls) you may try use ref structs

Comment: You want to minimize object creation **and** create new instances for each request? That sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: What sort of load/scale are you serving here? This sounds  a lot like premature optimization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't be using static for your scenario - static means "shared" resource. That means if the member is static, it will be used (shared) by all instances of the current class. If the objects are not extremely big / expensive to create accordingly to the number of requests, it doesn't really matter for some kind of performance. GC will get rid of them as soon they are not relevant anymore. At this point, it seems as a overengineering/premature optimization, which would be useless, unless you are dealing with hundres of thousands request per seconds etc.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want those objects to be reused by subsequent calls to the Web server ... if, during processing, a new request comes in, I don't want the new request to see data in the prior request's static classes and properties.

Then you should not use `static` objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to manage object creation in an `asp.net` application is the **IoC** container. Basically, such a mechanism takes responsibility for object creation and release.

It allows you to configure how long every object should live. And whether it should be shared across `HTTP` requests or not.

Here you can find good examples and explanations of what it is [DI doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)